# Как поменять шаблон кнопки?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Как сделать, чтобы границы кнопки (при нажатии, наведении) были не прямоугольные, а заданной формы. Как на картинке, например

[image: пример формы кнопки]

Если просто вставить картинку как фон, нужные границы остаются до нажатия/наведения на кнопку.

[image: кнопка во время нажатия]

Comment: Во-первых, вы выбрали неправильный язык: ваять GUI на managed C++ сплошное мучение. И вообще, что угодно делать на нём - мучение. Изменить форму кнопки придётся отрисовкой вручную. [Простой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815920/5045688) пример. [Полный](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/592/448/lecture/9999?page=8) пример. Примеры на C#, переведёте на C++/CLI сами. Непосредственно на этом языке примеры вряд ли найдёте (почему - смотрите начало моего комментария).

Comment: Кстати, если возникнут проблемы с переводом с C# на C++/CLI, то можно оставить на C#: сделать библиотеку dll с компонентом-кнопкой и подключить её к проекту. Платформа .NET тем и хороша, что позволяет разрабатывать на нескольких языках.